# Proper ergonomics for a standing desk?

Tags: posture, skeleton

I am considering having one of my desks raised to standing height.

There are detailed [OSHA guidelines](http://www.osha.gov/Publications/videoDisplay/figure3.jpg) for example

[image: OSHA diagram of ergonomic desk sitting.]

Are there similarly standard guidelines for how to set up a standing office work environment?

Comment: As you consider a standing desk, understand that prolonged standing can cause some [problems](http://hazards.org/standing/index.htm).

Comment: @BackInShapeBuddy good point - as mentioned in the OP, I am fortunate enough to have two desks; but as mentioned below, perhaps an adjustable desk would be ideal.

Comment: I missed that you have 2 desks which is ideal (or as you say an adjustable desk).  It allows you to switch off so that you avoid problems from any one prolonged position.  This [q/a](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/7781/should-i-get-rid-of-my-office-chair/7918#7918) gives some other ideas for varying your positioning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure this is from OSHA, but this is a diagram that I found on the subject:

[image]

Comment: This design looks good.

Comment: The desk above seems to be fixed. I think it should be possible to change the height depending on whether you stand or sit.

Comment: You could also just have a tall chair.

Comment: This diagram makes sense, but it'd be better to state where it came from, so I can evaluate whether it's a site I should trust or not.

Answer (score 2):

[Here are the guidelines](http://www.osha.gov/SLTC/etools/computerworkstations/positions.html) from OSHA for both sitting and standing desks.

Comment: The OP already links to the OSHA guidelines, so he probably is aware of your link. Additionally, as soon as the link dies, your post will be useless.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize that I wasn't allowed to post links. I thought it was a pretty standard way of sharing information on the internet

Comment: StackExchange does not try to share but to collect information, when the link dies because of [link rot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot), your post will be useless. It would be good to extract the important information from the link and add it as a citation.

Answer (score 2):

I recently purchased the [Ikea Sit and Stand desk](http://iamnotaprogrammer.com/Ikeas-own-standing-desk.html). It has been the solution I was looking for for a long time. You may want to give that one a shot. I got the electric one, which runs just under $500, but they also have a manual (with a lever), that pretty much does the same thing. I highly encourage anyone wanting to have the sitting and standing options on the same desk to give this desk a shot. They gave me (not sure if this is standard) a 90 day refund no questions asked guarantee, so it is worth a shot.

Comment: How does this answer the question _"Are there similarly standard guidelines for how to set up a standing office work environment?"_