# Length of sit vs. stand at adjustable desk?

Tags: lower-back, posture, foot-care

Are there any general guidelines (not hard rules), on how long you should sit vs. stand at an adjustable desk? Especially as you begin to adjust to one. This is in part following up on the answer to [Should I get rid of my office chair?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/7785/7660). I can see how it will be vary based on personal fitness and situation.

Also, are there any recommendations on foot position and stance while standing? I'm very new to sit-stand desks, and so far I've taken to a squat stance. Part of my issue has been hip mobility and pelvic tilt "butt wink" when performing barbell squats in the gym.

Comment: There are no "rules" that I know of... I use a 50-50 mix between standing up and using an exercise ball (I don't every use an office chair as this just means pains in the lower back the next day...)

Comment: Not really looking for rules (not in the firm, this is the way you must do it), more general recommendations. Such as when you do a 50-50 mix on the exercise ball, how are you braking it up across an 8 hour day, is it 4 on, 4 off, or is it more variable? And do you remember how you first adjusted to it?

Comment: Whenever I'm tired of sitting, I stand up and vice versa. It is often something like every 30 minutes or whenever I go for a new cup of coffee (ohh yes, I drink far too much coffee, but that is a different story)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there are rules *(I'm not even sure that people would follow them)* concerning those; however, my goal is to keep moving as much as possible. 
 
First, *as best as your back allows*try to sit straight always. Even if you rest your back on the chair, always try to be straight and not slouched. Sitting straight improves your posture as well as works your core muscles. So, my stomach naturally feels contracted without exercising it.  
 
Sometimes, I rock *(sideways sometimes, back and forth on others)* on my chair. Every hour, I do some crunches as well on my seat. Or I can lift both legs *(or alternate them)* for a few seconds to work my thighs. 
 
Squatting is good; however, it shouldn't be for an extended period. 
 
Whatever you do, ensure to move your body as much as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt but I'm not really looking for hard rules. I'm transitioning from a purely seated position (with a generally self-aware posture) to a sit-stand. So I'm looking for advice or information regarding how to transition, and what standing posture and positioning are advised.