# Prevent back issues on the go, i.e. without office chair?

Tags: posture

Common scenario for those who telecommute while traveling: You have to do extended office work in a hotel room, or in a rented apartment. Often there is no office chair, only a simple table and a standard chair, plus sometimes a couch and pillows. Back problems come quickly, sometimes already after a few hours.

*Is there any remedy, such as a certain sitting posture?*

Of course, one could just rent a desk in a coworking space, but not everybody likes the hustle and bustle in some of these places.

Comment: The following q/a may be helpful:  [Exercises to improve sitting posture](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6994/i-have-extremely-bad-posture-what-can-i-do/7015#7015).  Using an [exercise ball as a chair](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/1762/is-it-a-good-idea-to-use-an-exercise-ball-as-a-chair).  As far as specific hardware solutions that would be off topic here, but there are [cushions](http://astore.amazon.com/howtogetbackinshape-20/detail/B002C9ERMY) that can be used for back support or to sit upon. (Disclosure -  the picture is from our site's amazon store.)

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas you might want to try:

- Sit in the aforementioned hideous chair but put a lumbar support of some type in there. A pillow wedged between the small of your back and the chair will help to some degree. If you google "Lumbar Support Pad" you'll see commercial versions you may want to consider purchasing; they're better than pillows that never seem to work well.
- Lay on the ground and work. Lay on your stomach with a pillow under your belly, lay on your back with your knees popped up, move around. Sit cross legged and type with your laptop in front of you. The idea is that for an hour you'll end up moving around three or four different times to get comfortable which is arguably better than being comfortable in one position for an hour straight.